# pasting a folder through an sftp connection in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, sftp

I want to paste a folder through notepad++ to a repository I connect to through sftp. Notepad++ only allows me to upload one file at a time which is not very practical. Any ideas other that winSCP (it has too many bugs and I cannot run it from my laptop...). I am running windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at other tools that let you "mount" the remote server as a local drive-letter?  Something like  [expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/).   or perhaps you could use rsync or [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to make a mirror of the remote repository through ssh & update the remote after you've made changes... or you can try & hack something together like [tunneling a samba session through ssh](http://support.cs.toronto.edu/wiki/RemoteAccess/SSHTunneling/WindowsSamba) .